# Downcasting usng wrappers compared to primitives

Tags: java

Given:

```
double x = 15d;
```

Which method of conversion should I use:

```
int val = (int)x;
```

Or:

```
int val = new Double(x).intValue();
```

What ore the advantages of one and the other?

Comment: I would say there's no great impact unless you're working on critical real-time short-memory applications. If this is your case, then use the former. Otherwise, use the one you feel better. IMO I would opt for the former for simplicity of code.

Comment: Double.intValue probably uses the (int) cast internally; just use the former

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`new Double(x).intValue();` seems like it would be (trivially) less efficient, though I have nothing to back that up. Realistically, there are no functional advantages either way. However, I find that `(int)x` is much more readable, which is a significant advantage.

But most importantly, [premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Comment: The phrase *"premature optimization is the root of all evil"* is prematurely optimized. If you're going to quote it, at least quote the whole quote, and not just the pithy part.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference that I know of is that doing the second one has to create a new object of the class `Double` before returning an integer value back (with the call `.intValue()`).

The first one you mention does not have to create a new object before returning the integer value back.

This is why I personally use the first one:

```
int val = (int) x;
```

Comment: `new Double` doesn't create an anonymous object, it creates a `Double` object.

Comment: What do you call an object that is not stored in a variable? I've always called that an anonymous object (because it doesn't have a name). I'm not confusing it with an anonymous class definition--a different concept.

Comment: There's no name for that because there's really no need for a name for that. You shouldn't use *anonymous* because that is a name for something else, and that is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, they are equivalent (yield the same result). The second one is wasteful (because of object allocation), and less readable. There is no reason for using it in favor of `(int) x` whatsoever.

You could also do something like this: `Integer.parseInt(String.format("%.0f", x))`, it would also work. Just because you can do something, does not mean you should.